# Is possible get olny form fields have Similar Name of model properties in update method of resource controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `Course` Model that have many fields like this :

```
course_id
title
description
creator
start_date
end_date
reg_start_date
reg_end_date
picture
lesson_count
cost
status
active
teacher
created_at
updated_at
deleted_at
```

And I have a Form to edit a specified Model. action attribute of the  edit form tag is referenced to `course.update` route.

In the edit Form,in addition to fields with same names of above Model properties, there are many other form fields that not related to `Course` Model (and used for manyTomany relations or other operations)

Now in public update method , when I want to use Eloquent `update()` method , Since the number of irrelevant field names are many, I must to use except() method for incoming request. like this :

```
public
        function update (StoreCourseRequest $request, $id)
        {
            $data = $request->except(['search_node', '_token', 'start_date_picker', 'end_date_picker', 'reg_start_date_picker', 'reg_end_date_picker', 'orgLevels', 'courseCats','allLessonsTable_length']);

            $course = Course::findOrFail($id);

            $course->update($data);

            $course->org_levels()->sync($request->get('orgLevels'));
            $course->course_categories()->sync($request->get('courseCats'));

            $result = ['success' => true];

            return $result;
        }
```

As you see on usage of $request->except() method, I passed many field names to it to filter only proper attributes for use in `$course->update($data);`.

Now my Question is that Are there any way that we can get only same name model attributes from a field name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are trying to avoid having to use the `except()` method for incoming requests, correct?

If that is the case, you can just skip it altogether and pass the entire request to the `update()` method as it will only update matching fields (provided they are listed as "fillable" in the method class). This process is called ["mass-assignment"](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment).